# Websockets in Flash

Tags: html, flash, sockets, websocket

Two connected qustions

I understand that non HTML5 browser can connect to websockets using flash.

https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

**1.** However is there an implementation of websockets for flash inside flash?

**2.** If I were to use normal flash sockets, would the sockets work if there were multiple instances of the flash file running on a local network connecting to an external socket server. Would the messages intended for one instance be forwarded to all instances

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Here is a Flash implementation for use in Flash itself: https://github.com/y8/websocket-as
2. I'm not sure what you are asking but it sounds more like a question about the WebSockets server application and that completely depends on your application.